# the octal representations of bytes range from 000 to 377?

Tags: javascript, php, assembly

i am reading a book named "CODE" there i read a sentence "the octal representations of bytes range from 000 to 377" i don't understand how ? where does 377 comes from ? could some one please explain it thanks in advance .

Comment: `0377` is the octal representation of 255...

Comment: can you please explain a bit more what, what why does hexadecimal is used instead of octal number system what is the problem with octal decimal number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The octal value 0377 represents 255 in decimal which would be the range of a single byte.

The reason why hexadezimal and octal numbers are usefull is, because in hex a single digit represents exactly four bits, while in octal a single digits reprsents exactly three bits. this makes it much easier to convert to binary reading when dealing with flags, in contrast to decimal, where you'd have to know which numbers represent which bit, and do some calculation.

If you have an arbitrary bitmask, you can easily tell with one glance which bits are set if you use either hex or octal, which is not so easy with decimal numbers.

Answer (score 3):

377 octal is 255 decimal, which is highest possible value of one byte.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more what, what why does hexadecimal is used instead of octal number system what is the problem with octal decimal number?

Comment: See @Devolus great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Today [a byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) practically always consists of 8 bits. With 8 bits, you can represent 2^8 (256) different values (typically from 0-255 (unsigned)). And as others explained already 255 == ff ([base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_base) 16) == 255 (base 10) == 0377 (base 8) == 11111111 (base 2).

This value comes out very nice in hexadecimal, since single digit represents four bits (as there are 16 (2^4) hexadecimal digits), meaning two digit hexadecimal number always fit one byte.

Octal numeral system is pretty much out of use. Once it was much more common, as some computers used word sizes divisible by three (as explained [in this wikipedia article on Octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal#in%20computers)).