# Strange FormatException when converting to octal

Tags: c#, decimal, octal

So I have an *integer* number `208` I don't expect many to understand *why* I am doing this, but the end result of what I am trying to do is get the base-10 representation of octal number 208 (two-zero-eight). I expect that the confusing thing (for people that will try and answer this question) is that while 208 is an integer, I am using it more like a string containing the characters two, zero, and eight. **Please let me know if there are any more questions on this, as I think it will cause some confusion.**

Anyway, to get the base-10 representation of "208" here is what I do:

1. Convert `int` 208 into `string` "208".
2. Take the `string` "208", and parse from *octal* to *decimal*.

Then, here is the corresponding source code:

```
public byte OctalToDecimal(int octalDigits)
{
    byte decimalValue = 0;
    string octalString = string.Empty;

    // first, get a string representation of the integer number
    octalString = octalDigits.ToString();

    // now, get the decimal value of the octal string
    decimalValue = Convert.ToByte(octalString, 8);

    // set the decimal-value as the label
    return decimalValue;
}
```

I get a format exception when `octalDigits = 208`. I get a message about there being additional characters in the `octalString`'s value. Why would that be? All I do is convert from `int` to `string` it's very short/simple, and not like I append anything on there. What is going on?

Comment: That's because `8` is _not a valid digit_ for octal numbers. Octal symbols range from `0` to `7`!

Comment: 208 is *not* a valid octal number. You *can't* have the digit 8 in an octal number. In any case, an `int` stores the actual value. Talking about base and representation is meaningless - there are none. Base-10 or 8 has meaning when trying to format the actual value to a string.

Comment: I suspect this is a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you have a problem X, think that Y is the solution so you ask about Y when you get into trouble. What is your *actual* problem?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Couldn't agree more. Thanks.

Comment: Although, when the exception message talks about having extra characters... Well, I thought that mislead me a little bit. But also I'll have to shamefully admit that I didn't know octal numbers ended at 7.

Comment: But I can now see that since 8 isn't recognized as a natural octal character, it would be identified as some unknown/extra character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that the digits for octal numbers are in the range 0 to 7

Here, some helpful links

[the octal representations of bytes range from 000 to 377?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900157/the-octal-representations-of-bytes-range-from-000-to-377)

http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Octal numbers can not contain digit 8, like base-10 representation can't contain "digit" 10 and binary can't contain digit 2.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer